Laplace's Equation and maximizing electrical work
Both Karapetoff's The Electrical Circuit (pg 27) and this paper claim that in a conductor of irregular shape, if the voltage at both ends is taken constant the paths electric currents inside take will be that which maximises the power spent by the conductor, and if the current at both ends is taken constant the path electric currents inside take will be that which minimizes the power spent by the conductor. These paths give the conductor the least total resistance.
I find this easy to prove for the case of constant current. A conductor has uniform conductivity $\sigma$ and the currents through it are steady, so no charge accumulates at any point inside. We take a volume that is bounded by two types of surfaces. One surface $S$ through which current does not flow (This would be the outer surface of the wire), and surfaces $S1$, $S2$, etc. through which it does (these are the terminals of our resistor). $\phi$ is the electric potential, $\vec E$ and $\vec J$ are the electric field and current density, respectively.
The total power spent overcoming throughout this volume is
$$P=\iiint \vec E \cdot \vec J \ dV=\iiint \sigma E^2 dV$$
The variation in this power is
$$\delta P = \iiint \sigma (\vec E\cdot\delta\vec E+\delta E^2) \ dV$$
To first approximation
$$\delta P = \iiint \sigma (\vec E\cdot\delta\vec E) \ dV = -\iiint\sigma(\nabla \phi\cdot\delta\vec E)\ dV = -\iiint\sigma[\nabla\cdot ( \phi\delta\vec E)-\phi \delta(\nabla \cdot\vec E)]\ dV $$
$$=-\iint_{S,S_1,S_2,...}\sigma\phi\delta\vec E\cdot\ d\vec S+\iiint\sigma\phi\delta (\nabla\cdot\vec E)\ dV$$
The surface integral vanishes since no current flows through $S$, and the current through $S1$, $S2$, etc. we don't vary. The volume integral vanishes since there is no charge buildup in the conductor, making $\nabla \cdot \vec E = 0$. Therefore, to first approximation, $\delta P = 0$
To second approximation, $\delta E^2$ is always positiove, so the integral containing it is positive regardless of what $\delta \vec E$ we choose. Then $\delta P \gt 0$, meaning $P$ is at a minimum. Since $P=I^2R$ and $I$ is held constant, the resistance is at a minimum.
I can't figure out how the corresponding result for constant voltage at the terminals could be obtained. I don't doubt the variation in power loss could be found $0$ to first approximation but I don't see how the second order variation could be made negative.
I'd like to see some books that mention the subject too if possible.

Your statement is wrong. If you force a current the power dissipation is minimum, not maximum. (Imagine: if the current would contract into a narrow corridor it would see higher resistance and dissipate much more, so you can always increase it, you cannot be at a maximum!)

I'm just repeating what the book and the paper say, fixed-voltage = maximized power and fixed-current = minimized power, both implying minimized resistance.
The paper (which seems to just take it as a given, unless I missed something) puts it as a fixed voltage pushing as much current as possible, or a fixed current going through with as little a voltage drop as possible.

The confusing part is: "... $P$  is at a maximum. Since $P=I^2R$
and $I$ is held constant, the resistance is at a minimum." I thought you were treating the constant-current case there, so it should be the opposite.

Ah, that was a mistake, yes. Corrected.

And for the actual question: wouldn't it suffice to use the fact that the solution for the current distribution in both cases is the same? So it minimizes $R$ which means it minimizes $P$ for constant current and it maximizes $P$ for constant voltage.

I would like to prove it through calculus of variations, since I could prove the fixed-current case. Besides, it doesn't seem to me obvious that if the correct current distribution minimizes $R$ compared a number of wrong distribution with the same boundary currents, it will also minimize $R$ compared to a number of wrong distributions with the same boundary voltages. It could be kind of like a saddle point, minimum in one axis and maximum in another. I know it isn't, but I would like to see proof of why.

But you did not consider "distribution with the same boundary currents", in the constant-current case! You kept $\phi$ constant, there was no $\delta\phi$, and only kept the total current through surfaces $S1, S2$ constant. Otherwise your statements about the surface integrals there would not hold. (So if you want to do it from first principles this first step was not right anyway, I mean.)

There was no $\delta \phi$ but there was $\delta \vec E$, which is proportional to the variation in current density, which I then set to $0$ at the boundaries
